# How to dynamically run a list of sql statements stored in a table and check results

Tags: postgresql

In our postgres db, I'm needing to run some data check statements that are stored in a table, then check the results of the queries to verify that the data being returned is expected.
Bonus points for sending failed results to a table and/or raising an error or warning.

An example of what I need in separate pieces would look like:

Create table with 10 records:

```
create table TheseAreRecords
(words varchar(20), numbers int);

insert into TheseAreRecords 
values 
('Hi', 1),('Bye',2),('Bye',3),('Bye',4),('Hi',5),('Bye',6),('Bye',7),('Hi',8),('Bye',9),('Bye',10);
```

| words | numbers |
| --- | --- |
| Hi | 1 |
| Bye | 2 |
| Bye | 3 |
| Bye | 4 |
| Hi | 5 |
| Bye | 6 |
| Bye | 7 |
| Hi | 8 |
| Bye | 9 |
| Bye | 10 |

Create table with data check queries:

```
create table TheseAreDataChecks
( checkname varchar, 
  sqlstring varchar,
  isactive boolean);

insert into TheseAreDataChecks
values ('Count_Hi','select count(*) from TheseAreRecords where words = ''Hi'';', true)
,('Count_Bye','select count(*) from TheseAreRecords where words = ''Bye'';', false)
,('Count_Bye_sans_2','select count(*) from TheseAreRecords where words = ''Bye'' and numbers <> 2;', true);
```

| checkname | sqlstring | isactive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Count_Hi | select count(*) from TheseAreRecords where words = 'Hi'; | true |
| Count_Bye | select count(*) from TheseAreRecords where words = 'Bye'; | false |
| Count_Bye_sans_2 | select count(*) from TheseAreRecords where words = 'Bye' and numbers <> 2; | true |

What I'm struggling with is creating a function or some kind of procedure (sorry, I am way more well-versed with sql server) that will be able to run the data checks in TheseAreDataChecks where `isactive = true`.

I have tried looking for how to use dynamic sql to do this, as well as running loops in postgres, but I haven't been able to get either to work.

It doesn't matter what order the queries from the table run in, or whether they run concurrently.

*Bonus:*
Would it be better (from a best practices standpoint) to write results to a table and run separate checks on that table to verify that we're getting the results that are expected? Or would it be better to build the verification into the check queries themselves?

Comment: Will you ever have something different than a `select count(*)` query to validate? And how do you validate the checks? I don't see any column that contains the expected result. Btw: the table name "`theseare records` is misleading, because those are _rows_ not "records" ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes! These are just super simple queries to test the functionality - the actual data and data check queries are going to be more complex (in most cases) than these! 

And you're exactly right - poor word choice on my part lol

Also the expected result may change, so the verification, to some extent, would always be a true/false, or is x within a range, or something like that. That would be built into the data checks queries (though not in this example to keep it simple).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the queries dynamically using `query_to_xml()`. The tricky part will be extracting useful information from the resulting XML.

Something along the lines:

```
select checkname, 
       (xpath('/table/row/count/text()', query_to_xml(sqlstring, false, false, '')))[1]::text
from thesearedatachecks
where isactive
```

Given your sample data that would return:

```
checkname        | xpath
-----------------+------
Count_Hi         | 3    
Count_Bye_sans_2 | 6
```

If you don't really know what the queries return, you can just extract the `row` tag:

```
select checkname, 
       (xpath('/table/row', query_to_xml(sqlstring, false, false, '')))[1]::text
from thesearedatachecks
where isactive
```

Which returns the following (based on your sample data):

```
checkname        | xpath             
-----------------+-------------------
Count_Hi         | <row>             
                 :   <count>3</count>
                 : </row>
Count_Bye_sans_2 | <row>             
                 :   <count>6</count>
                 : </row>
```

If the `Count_Hi` query was `select min(numbers), max(numbers) from ...` then the result would be:

```
checkname        | xpath             
-----------------+-------------------
Count_Hi         | <row>             
                 :   <min>1</min>
                 :   <max>8</max>
                 : </row>
Count_Bye_sans_2 | <row>             
                 :   <count>6</count>
                 : </row>
```

If your queries always return a single column, but you don't know the column's name, you could use the XPath expression `'/table/row/child::*/text()'`